# Serializing a std::function for a distributed population-based optimization application in C++

Tags: algorithm, c++11, distributed-computing, mathematical-optimization, hpc

Hopefully the title of this question conveys the general concept that I am looking for assistance in designing/implementing.

To clarify:

I am trying to write a distributed application to perform optimization.  The general approach will follow that of a genetic algorithm: I am trying to find a vector of parameters which minimizes the value of some cost function.

My present difficulty deals with the cost function itself.  I am trying to make the design as generic as I possibly can; therefore, my intent is to use a std::function as an argument to the optimizer class.

**Specifically, my question centers around: how can I share information about this cost function to the distributed nodes?**

A couple more details:

- The computation nodes are intended to be fully decoupled.  This type of algorithm is *embarrassingly parallel* and requires no communication between each of the nodes.
- It has been my intention, therefore, not to use MPI (or related message-passing approaches), but rather to use a scheduler such as Condor or SGE (most likely the former) to spawn instances of the application on available nodes.  The nodes will be given a lookup key for retrieving its candidate vector from a database.
- I can use the *Factory Pattern* to instantiate objects of a given cost function type; however, I am looking for an alternate approach.  (I'm not sure what it is about using a Factory class that I find disagreeable)
- I am obviously not looking for a way to execute arbitrary code on a remote machine.  Each node runs a full instance of the executable.

As an aside, I am making fairly extensive use of Boost throughout and am highly amenable to an alternative solution using Boost functionality.

I'd appreciate if anyone can offer some advice on how to distribute the cost function to other nodes.  As well, I'd also greatly appreciate if anyone can point out whether there is something flawed with my general design concept.

**Update:**

Valid or not, one of my hesitations regarding a factory pattern for the cost function, involves the configuration/parameters/details of the cost function.  There are certain assumptions and/or specs that I can assign to this family of classes: the objects that it is expecting to operate on, etc.  I am already passing various options to other Factory classes elsewhere in the design and I find it adds to the complexity.

Perhaps a bit of additional clarification on the context is warranted:

I am using this optimizer as a module in an app for the purpose of modeling data.  The details of the model are, in fact, parsed into an AST and passed to a Factory class which passes arguments to the applicable model class(es).

Therefore, the optimizer has a reference to the model itself, can call a Calculate(Iterator&) method on the model and expect a Matrix as a return value (fyi, the Iterator is a reference to the parameter Vector).

That part is straightforward.  What I find to be less straightforward is then determining what to do with the returned matrix.  Certainly, a simple cost function might simply be a least-squares.  But I can conceive of relatively complex functions as well which may themselves be parameterized.  I can deal with that, as well, but I was hoping that there might be a completely different approach -- one that I haven't thought of, which might help to simplify what I am doing.

Thanks and kind regards,

Shmuel

Comment: You cannot serialize the function, instead you need to think of using some form of messaging etc. where you would pass some key/value to indicate to each executable which function should run. Why not store this along with the vector?

Comment: @Nim, That has been generally my thought as well (and my specific intent when I mentioned Factory Pattern above).  I was just hoping that there might be a different possibility.  One of my concerns with passing information to the nodes on which function should run, deals with the parameters of the said function. I'll also add a bit more details to the question to better articulate some of my feelings on the matter.  Thanks for your comment -- I do appreciate it!

Comment: You can serialize a function. Source code is one form of serialization. An expression tree would be another.

Comment: This is a very foggy question. What do you mean by serializing a function?

Comment: @TamásSzelei, additional clarification added to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @NickC, I don't think I fully grasp your comment.  I did add a bit more context to my question above, which might better explain what I am trying to do.  Can I ask to please clarify what you meant in your comment?

Comment: If everything else is embarrassingly parallel, why mess that up for just the cost function?  Presumably each instance runs its own factory for the model, so why would each instance not just run its own factory for the cost functor?  You must already have some config framework.  What benefit would you get by running a factory on one instance and trying to distribute the result?